# Quasi-nilpotent operator with finite-dimensional kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can we find an operator $T$ on a Banach space with the following properties?

a) $\sigma_p(T)=\sigma(T)=\{0\}$.

b) $\ker T$ is of finite dimension.

c) $TX$ is a closed and finite-codimensional subspace of $X$?

Comment: Do you want $X$ to be infinite-dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = \mathbb{C}^2$.
The matrix
$$
T = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 \ & 1 \\ 0 \ & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
has double eigenvalue $0$, and in finite dimensions the point spectrum and spectrum are identical, so we have $\sigma_p(T)=\sigma(T)=\{0\}$.
It is easy to see that the kernel of $T$ is the linear span of the first basis vector.
In particular it is finite dimensional.
Consequently, $TX$ has co-dimension one in $X$, and is trivially closed.